# How to properly apply time series classification on a problematic data?

Tags: time-series

I would like to apply this work https://github.com/Vidhiwar/multimodule-ecg-classification/tree/master. In that GitHub link, (http://www.timeseriesclassification.com/description.php?Dataset=ECG5000) ECG5000 data is used. I have univariate data. In this data and in my data, columns are timestamps. Each row represents 24 hours measurement of a person. My problem is that my data has missing values at some time. Each row has different start and end time. Rows in my data do not have always same measurement time. I am thinking of only considering most available data overlapping time, and taking only that part. Do you have any alternative solutions for my data pre-processing problem?